# Guava copyOf nested collections

Tags: java, guava

Let's say I have the following Map definition:

```
Map<String, List<Set<Integer>>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put("a", Arrays.asList(Sets.newHashSet(1, 2, 3), Sets.newHashSet(4, 5)));
```

I create an immutable copy of the map as follows:

```
ImmutableMap<String, List<Set<Integer>>> immutableMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(map);
```

If I call `immutableMap.get("a").add(Sets.newHashSet(4));`I get an error indicating that the nested
List is also immutable in the copied collection. However, if the call to 
`immutableMap.get("a").get(1).add(6);` can be executed and if I printout the result I will get:

`{a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}`

Does it mean that `copyOf` only makes nested immutable collections one-level deep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's because `Arrays#asList(Object...)` returns an fixed-size `List`, ie. from which you cannot add or remove elements.

The [`ImmutableMap#copyOf(..)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) javadoc states

> Returns an immutable map containing the same entries as map.

So the value of the entry with key `"a"` is the `List` returned by `Arrays#asList(Object...)`.